# Haskell instance function

Tags: haskell, card

I'm solving some exercises from a book and now I'm having some difficulties:
In this exercise I shall implement Card as an instance of the class Ord.
But I don't know how exactly I could implement it, so I would appreciate any help.

My code so far looks like this:

```
data Suit = Diamond | Club | Spade | Heart

data Rank = Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

data Card = Card Suit Rank

instance Ord Card where
 ....
```

Now I don't know how exactly to implement this and I would very much like to understand it.
Thanks in advance for the explanations.

Comment: I don't think `data Card = Suit | Rank` does what you think. By analogy, if it did, consider what `data Suit = Diamond | Heart` would mean.

Comment: I edited it, is it correct now?

Comment: You have to define either `(Card s1 r1) <= (Card s2 r2) = ...` or `compare (Card s1 r1) (Card s2 r2) = ...` What problem are you having? (Note this means defining `Ord` instances for `Suite` and `Rank` first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ask GHCi for information about `Ord`.

```
:info Ord
```

This shows the class definition, followed by a list of instances.

```
type Ord :: * -> Constraint
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  max :: a -> a -> a
  min :: a -> a -> a
  {-# MINIMAL compare | (<=) #-}
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
```

Its superclass is `Eq`, and `:info Eq` tells us:

```
type Eq :: * -> Constraint
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  {-# MINIMAL (==) | (/=) #-}
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
```

So in order to implement `Ord` for `Card`, we need two things:

- An `instance Ord Card`, with a definition of `compare` or `(<=)`
- An `instance Eq Card` with a definition of `(==)` or `(/=)`

Since these instances are very mechanical to write, normally we ask the compiler to derive them automatically:

```
data Suit = Diamond | Heart | Spade | Club
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Rank = Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Card = Card Suit Rank
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

If you pass the `-ddump-deriv` flag to GHC, or use `:set -ddump-deriv` in GHCi, it will print out the code that it generates for these instances.

However, the task is to understand how to implement these instances by hand, so let’s go through it step by step.

We’ll start with `Eq`. For `Suit` and `Rank`, we need to specify that each constructor is equal to itself (a.k.a. *reflexivity*) and all other constructors are unequal.

```
instance Eq Suit where
  Diamond == Diamond  = True
  Heart   == Heart    = True
  Spade   == Spade    = True
  Club    == Club     = True
  _       == _        = False

instance Eq Rank where
  Seven == Seven  = True
  Eight == Eight  = True
  Nine  == Nine   = True
  Ten   == Ten    = True
  Jack  == Jack   = True
  Queen == Queen  = True
  King  == King   = True
  Ace   == Ace    = True
  _     == _      = False
```

With that out of the way, we can define `==` for `Card` in a similar way, by pattern-matching on values of the form `Card suit rank`.

```
instance Eq Card where

  -- Two cards are equal if…
  Card suit1 rank1 == Card suit2 rank2

    -- …their suits are equal,
    -- and their ranks are equal.
    = …
```

There are two conventional ways to define the body. One is spelling it out literally: `suit1 == suit2 && rank1 == rank2`. Another is to use tuples: `(suit1, rank1) == (suit2, rank2)`.

Again, to define `Ord`, we can begin with the instances for the enumerations `Suit` and `Rank`. We have two choices of how to specify these: `(<=)` or `compare`. The direct option is to just list out the table of possible cases, abbreviating cases where we can:

```
instance Ord Suit where

  Diamond <= _        = True

  Heart   <= Diamond  = False
  Heart   <= _        = True

  Spade   <= Diamond  = False
  Spade   <= Heart    = False
  Spade   <= _        = True

  Club    <= Club     = True
  Club    <= _        = False

instance Ord Rank where

  …
```

For `Card`, we now just need to follow the same basic form as for `Eq`. Since we defined `(<=)` for `Suit` and `Rank`, note that we automatically get a default implementation of the other comparison functions like `compare` and `(<)` for those types.

```
instance Ord Card where

  -- Two cards are in order if…
  Card suit1 rank1 <= Card suit2 rank2
    -- …one rank is less than the other,
    -- or their ranks are equal and suits are in order.
    = …
```

Again you can translate this comment verbatim using `(<)`, `(||)`, `(==)`, `(&&)`, `(<=)`.

Try implementing these instances based on `compare` instead of `(<=)`. Hint: use `comparing` and `instance Monoid Ordering` from `Data.Ord`.

Add `deriving (Enum)` to `Rank` and `Suit`—try using `fromEnum` to simplify their `Eq` and `Ord` definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine the exercise actually wanted you to manually write the necessary instances.  Especially for `Suit` and `Rank`, they would be very tedious (and error prone) to write.

Instead, you probably want to use the `deriving` keyword to automatically derive the necessary instances.  If you write:

```
data Suit = Diamond | Heart | Spade | Club
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

this automatically derives `Eq` and `Ord` instances.  (The `Eq` instance is required by the `Ord` instance.)  The derived `Eq` instance is self-explanatory, and the derived `Ord` instance uses the order in which the constructors appear in the declaration, so `Diamond` is the smallest and `Club` is the biggest.  If you want bridge order, use:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

instead.  Similarly,

```
data Rank = Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

orders the rank from `Seven` (smallest) to `Ace` (largest).  Then, if you write:

```
data Card = Card Rank Suit
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

the derived instance sorts `Cards` according to the first field `Rank`, with ties broken by `Suit`.  If you wrote:

```
data Card = Card Suit Rank
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

it would instead order them by `Suit`, then `Rank`.

Some code to illustrate:

```
data Suit = Diamond | Heart | Spade | Club
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Rank = Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Card = Card Rank Suit
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

main = do
  let heart8 = Card Eight Heart
      spade8 = Card Eight Spade
      diamond7 = Card Seven Diamond

  print $ heart8 == heart8   -- True
  print $ heart8 == spade8   -- False
  print $ heart8 < spade8    -- True
  print $ diamond7 < spade8  -- True
```